# What is wrong with my tuple?

Tags: python, compiler-errors, tuples

I created a function to take in a text file with such data:

```
2012-01-01  09:00   Angel   Men's Clothing  214.05  Amex
2012-01-01  09:00   Ben Women's Clothing    153.57  Visa
2012-01-01  09:00   Charlie Music   66.08   Cash
```

and it converts that into a list of tuples:

```
Code : myList = [tuple(j.split("\t")) for j in stringX.split("\n")]
Result:
[('2012-01-01', '09:00', 'Angel', "Men's Clothing", '214.05', 'Amex'), 
('2012-01-01', '09:00', 'Ben', "Women's Clothing", '153.57', 'Visa'), 
('2012-01-01', '09:00', 'Charlie', 'Music', '66.08', 'Cash')]
```

And further converts it into this:

```
Code: nameList = [(float(item[4]),item[2])for item in myList]
Result: [(214.05, 'Angel'), (153.57, 'Ben'), (66.08, 'Charlie')]
```

With that small sized text file, its running perfectly. But I have to convert a big text file that is over 200 MB with over 1 million lines. It manages to convert into list of tuples but it doesn't convert further into the smaller list of tuples as shown above.

It gives me the error when i run the program with the Big File:

```
File "C:\Users\Charlie\Desktop\PYC\PYTHON ASSIGNMENT\test3.py", line 34, in <listcomp>
nameList = [(float(item[4]),item[2])for item in myList]
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Comment: Are you sure this was not an empty line you are reading? You have to check the "item" length before using it in this way.

Comment: i think there is an extra empty line in the text file.. so `stringX` will have `'\n'` at the end.. and when you split, use get  `('',)` as last element in `nameList`

Comment: it is `(' ',)` this problem! thank you very much. May i ask if there is a way for the code to ignore the empty line? @JeroenHeier @type_none

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You tuple has an empty entry that is why you are getting *"IndexError: tuple index out of range"*

You can add an if condition to validate if the tuple has any values in it.

**EX:**

```
myList = [('2012-01-01', '09:00', 'Angel', "Men's Clothing", '214.05', 'Amex'), 
('2012-01-01', '09:00', 'Ben', "Women's Clothing", '153.57', 'Visa'),
(), 
('2012-01-01', '09:00', 'Charlie', 'Music', '66.08', 'Cash')]


nameList = [(float(item[4]),item[2])for item in myList if item]
print nameList
[(214.05, 'Angel'), (153.57, 'Ben'), (66.08, 'Charlie')]
```